# Generate XML with child nodes from other classes with JAXB and Jersey

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, jersey

I try to generate a XML from a webservice using JAXB with Hibernate.

Main class is Tabla which has a child node of type Alumno class. I need to generate XML with data from Tabla class and from child node Alumno.

I accept two possibilities:
1. Add a link to XML from Tabla data link to Alumno XML
2. Add a child node to Tabla XML with include info from Alumno class (I prefer this one).

I tried second option with this configuration but always I get error 500 from server:

**Tabla class**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@XmlSeeAlso(Alumno.class)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "tabla")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"id", "alumno", "fechaInicio" })
public class Tabla implements java.io.Serializable {

    @XmlElement
    private Integer id;
    @XmlElement
    private Alumno alumno;
    @XmlElement
    private Date fechaInicio;

    public Tabla() {
    }

    public Tabla(Integer id,Date fechainicio, Alumno alumno) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.fechaInicio = fechainicio;
        this.alumno = alumno;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Alumno getAlumno() {
        return alumno;
    }

    public void setAlumno(Alumno alumno) {
        this.alumno = alumno;
    }

    public Date getFechainicio() {
        return fechaInicio;
    }

    public void setFechainicio(Date fechainicio) {
        this.fechaInicio = fechainicio;
    }
}
```

**Alumno class**

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "alumno")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"nombre", "apellidos"})
public class Alumno implements java.io.Serializable {

    @XmlAttribute
    private Integer id;
    @XmlElement
    private String nombre;

    public Alumno() {
    }

    public Alumno(String nombre, String apellidos) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return this.apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }
}
```

Hibernate config is OK because I tried by code to get a list of Tabla's including Alumno info and Hibernate lazy correctly info from Alumno entity. So problem happends when I try to marshall Tabla to XML.

I see try also with XMLAdapter but I don't know how can I implement for these case.

Comment: You don't need to mix view models and DAO. But anyway, look following article to find more info about JAX-RS
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

Comment: JAXB example from test
https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/jaxb/